# CS0117 C# 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Drawable'

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

after I finally managed to setup a custom renderer, I wanna change the shape of every button in my app. Sounds easy, huh?

Setup:

Xamarin.Forms Version 2.3.2.127

Xamarin.Android.Support.* Version 23.3.0

My custom renderer:

```
var btn = this.Control as Android.Widget.Button;
btn.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.arrow_button);
```

When I try to build & deploy it, the Error List gives me the following error:

```
CS0117  C# 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Drawable'
```

How can I resolve this error?

Cheers!

Comment: Which Android SDKs did you install? Check under Tools > Android > Android SDK manager. You're probably missing one. I think Xamarin recommends to install a low one like 14 and 23 and the latest or something

Comment: Marshmallow (Level 23) is installed (and targeted in the Manifest-File)

Comment: Do you have Android in your namespace?

Comment: Try to remove Resources/Resource.Designer.cs file in Android project and then build project, it will regenerate that file in same location and you will need to add it to project manually.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong Resource namespace. I had to use Droid.Resource in my project like this:

```
btn.SetBackgroundResource(Droid.Resource.Drawable.arrow_button);
```

Otherwise Xamarin doesn't know which Resource you mean, so you got to name it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do when this one surfaces...

- [right-mouse] droid project
- open 'application' tab
- set min android to android 4.4 / api19
- hit [x] to close android manifest
- [right-mouse] droid project
- [click] open folder in in file explorer
- delete "bin" and "obj" directories
- rebuild PCL
- rebuild Droid

Good luck.  Healy in Tampa.

Comment: sadly, sometimes I hit a point with these where I just "start clean" and copy everything in.  wish I could offer better.

Comment: I'm sure you've done this, but open Android SDK Manager from Tools > Android and make sure right API levels to match your android manifest min and max are installed.

Answer (score -1):

I sort ran into similar error.
It might that you are missing

```
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
```

and make sure that your drawables are in png format, because jpg-s dont work.
if this doesnt help, ill delete my answer

Comment: Even if this isn't the correct answer, i think you could keep it for future reference.